# Android: Trying to add admod to a second activity that I start with an intent

Tags: java, android, admob

I have an application that has a start up screen and when the user clicks a button it starts the real app in a new activity using an intent.  When I try to add admob adds to the second activity the app just crashes.

I took a sample app off admobs web site and modified it to replicate what I am doing.  I get the same results.  The adds work on the first actiivity, but when I start the second activity it just crashes.

Here is my code

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.google.ads.example"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="BannerXML"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
</manifest>
```

Main XML from original sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.ads.example"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>              

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Original Source code with my added code to start new activity

```
public class BannerXML extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  final Button myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  myBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            start_new_activity();
        }
       });

  // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
  AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}


private void start_new_activity()
{
     Intent i = new Intent(BannerXML.this, test_add.class);
    this.startActivity(i);  
    finish();
}
}
```

My new activity class

```
public class test_add extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); 
}
}
```

My XML for second layout activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:text="This is a test" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </TextView>
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView1"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adUnitId="a14e449d41a7dbe"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem seems to be something with the XML for my new layout.  Even if I never do an add request in the second activity it still crashes when it starts

Any Help Would Be Appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Post the exception log please

Answer (score 0):

In your Manifest, there is no declaration for the test_add activity..

Also I suggest respecting the CamelCase convention for naming Java classes